# Should I assert types in TypeScript by casting or checking the type with instanceof?

Tags: typescript, casting, typechecking

What should be the preferred way of asserting object types in TypeScript? Is it always more appropriate to explicitly check the type using `instanceof`, or by asserting the compiler with the `as` keyword, when we know what the type should be?

Say we have a `onclick` event handler, where `event.target` is altered:

```
function handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  event.target.style.display = "block"; 
}
```

This is marked as error, since the type of `event.target` is `EventTarget | null`.

Would the better/more standard way to assert the type of `event.target` be to use `instanceof`, like this:

```
if (!(e.target && e.target instanceof HTMLElement)) return;
event.target.style.display = "block";
```

Or knowing that the `onclick` event is attached to a DOM element, should it be preferred to use the `as` keyword:

```
(e.target as HTMLElement).style.display = "block";
```

Comment: It depends. If you can't be sure, that a value is of the required type, asserting it would be unsafe. If you have a rare scenario, where TypeScript can't infer the correct type itself, but you now for sure, that the value has the required type, then an assertion would be appropriate.

Comment: It's an error because there are things you could potentially add a click handler to that aren't `HTMLElement`. See [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget), for example `SVGElement`, `Document`, maybe even `Window`. Even if the code doesn't do that now, that might come up in the future and silently fail because nobody remembers that implementation detail. in this case it would feel safer to me to have an explicit check in place but it ultimately depends on whether the code has potential to be used with something that isn't `HTMLElement`.